# Cloning a Git Repo from a Windows Dropbox Server

Tags: windows-7, repository, dropbox, git, clone

I've set up a git repo on my Windows desktop successfully, but I'm having a little difficulty cloning the repo onto my Ubuntu laptop.  I use TortoiseGit on my Windows desktop, but I want to start learning the actual commands for Git.  I've tried various iterations similar to:

```
git clone -o dropbox ~/Dropbox/sites/wordpress/
```

and

```
git clone -o dropbox ~/Dropbox/sites/wordpress/.git
```

but I get a `repository doesn't exist` message.  Now, on my Windows dropbox folder, the actual git repo is `/Dropbox/sites/wordpress/.git` but when I log into dropbox from their website (on my Ubuntu laptop), I can't see the .git repo.  So this might actually be a problem with hidden files on Windows, but I'm not 100% sure.  Either way, what would be the proper command to use to clone the repo?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the right path. Using '~' in the path won't work in windows. Please use the right path.